How to remove Firebase App Hosting project?
I'm using Firebase's new feature App Hosting. I have created a backend there but I no longer want it. How can I delete that from the project?
I don't mean the "hosting" option that has always been there, I mean the new App Hosting feature.
Thanks

I couldn't find a way to do this through the UI, but the CLI command from Jason's answer worked.

Sorry my earlier answer isn't correct. Try this instead:
firebase apphosting:backends:delete -l us-central1 my-backend-id 

I get
Error: apphosting:backends:delete is not a Firebase command

App hosting is a relatively new service, so your Firebase CLI version might be outdated. I’m using version 13.13.3, and the command works on my setup.

That's the correct way:
firebase apphosting:backends:delete --project PROJECT_ID BACKEND_ID --location us-central1


if you get the error "Error: apphosting:backends:delete is not a Firebase command" make sure to update your firebase-cli to the latest version

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
